# Declaring CPP objects inside cuda kernel

Tags: c++, c, oop, cuda

I am new to Cuda and I need to know its limits before running my C++ project via Cuda.
Suppose I have a C++ class called MyClass. Knowing that Cuda uses C99, **is it possible to declare an object of type MyClass inside a kernel?** Would the below code snippet be appropriate?

```
_global__ void SolveBlaBlaBLa(int x, ...)
{

MyClass obj1;
.
.
.
}
```

Thanks in Advance,
- Ruru

Comment: CUDA doesn't use C99 as a base, it follows C90 to which a significant amount of C++98 language features have been added.

Comment: If `MyClass` has a `__host__`-only constructor and destructor, your code will be illegal. You will need to ensure they are annotated with `__device__` or `__host__ __device__`.

Comment: @JaredHoberock Thank you for your response. In this case, I will have to work on the constructors and destructors to include the keyword _____device_____ ...that won't be a problem, I hope...thanks to you all. __device_

Answer (score 4):

Just providing an answer to get this off the unanswered list.  I think @JaredHoberock will not mind.

In general, CUDA supports a large subset of C++ functionality, including support for objects in device code.

*Any* code that executes on the device, however, must be properly decorated.  For ordinary individual functions (not kernels), the [decorator](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#function-type-qualifiers) that the compiler recognizes to create a device callable version of the code is `__device__`.   This applies to any object method which may be used on the device, including constructors and destructors.

You may also wish to familiarize yourself with other restrictions on C++ classes used in the device code, as [documented in the programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#classes).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @RobertCrovella. I don not understand the reason behind decorating an object inside the device! Would't be better that the compiler takes care of this? Because the object is already declared inside the device, or outside. I can take care of all the restrictions so that the object(s) compile well on both the CPU and the GPU.

Comment: The decoration is done at the class definition point.  Not when you instantiate the object.  There is no extra decoration required to instantiate the object.  If you take care of that restriction (decorating the methods at the class definition point) then it should work fine whether instantiated in host code or device code.